# bash.exe not working on Jenkins (Windows)

Tags: windows, bash, jenkins

When running a build under "Execute Windows batch command" with the "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe --version" it fails with the error "exit -1073741819".
If I run the same command on the windows command line on the same machine but locally, it works just fine.
Any inputs on where I am failing? I am trying to avoid using git or cygwin and just keep things equal as when I manually run it.

Prints:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens if you manually run this command? And where did you install this bash from?

Comment: I don't recall where I installed from. The output is: "GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law."

Comment: Manually,  you also invoke it from a Windows command line, in the same way as from Windows?  The exit code under Jenkins indicates an [access violation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/379441/error-code-34exited-with-code-107374181934.html). Perhaps it would help if you also post your Jenkins Job definition and Jenkins version.

Comment: Your question made me try using another bash.exe. I tried using the bash.exe from git and it worked,and looking to the version that says linux, it looks like it is running on WSL or within some unix that, I guess, jenkins cannot access on the run. 
I changed to "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" and, despite the warnings, it makes what I want. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use an _Execute shell_ build step if you want to work with Bash?